# Json.Net Custom ContractResolver Ignoring Custom Objects

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, serialization, json.net

Experiencing a very strange instance when using a custom ContractResolver with Json.Net.

I have the following model structure:

```cs
public class ParentClass
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public CustomModel Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomModel
{
    public string CustomItem1 { get; set; }
    public string CustomItem2 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
    public string Item4 { get; set; }
}
```

My task involves creating a JSON string that contains only serialized properties of the ParentClass model, like so:

```json
{
  "Item1": "abc",
  "Item2": {
    "CustomItem1": "def",
    "CustomItem2": "ghi"
  }
}
```

Hence, I created a custom contract resolver as follows:

```cs
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        return base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType).Where(member => member.DeclaringType == typeof(ParentClass) || typeof(ParentClass).IsSubclassOf(member.DeclaringType)).ToList();
    }
}
```

However when I use it in the following manner:

```cs
var instance = new ChildClass()
{
    Item1 = "abc",
    Item2 = new CustomModel()
    {
        CustomItem1 = "def",
        CustomItem2 = "ghi"
    },
    Item3 = "jkl",
    Item4 = "mno",
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, Formatting.Indented, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The following JSON is printed:

```json
{
  "Item1": "abc",
  "Item2": { }
}
```

Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMs9Hb).

If I do not use the contract resolver, the following JSON is printed:

```json
{
  "Item3": "jkl",
  "Item4": "mno",
  "Item1": "abc",
  "Item2": {
    "CustomItem1": "def",
    "CustomItem2": "ghi"
  }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mSpU7R).

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: After fixing compilation errors was not able to [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Ih8mH).

Comment: [mcve] here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMs9Hb.  Fix here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMs9Hb.  Because of some wretched google captcha I can't seem to post an answer.  Your question is somewhat broken because the code you wrote for *However when I use it in the following manner:* doesn't actually show the contract resolver being used.

Comment: Please check my edit of your question to see whether it is correct.  I *think* I have demonstrated the problem, but please make sure.

Comment: @GuruStron reason you were not able to reproduce it, is because you did not use the custom resolver.

Comment: @RyanFalzon yes, has not looked into copied code closely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CustomResolver` may be fixed as follows:

```
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var members = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
        if (objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ParentClass)))
            members = members.Where(m => m.DeclaringType == typeof(ParentClass)).ToList();
        return members;
    }
}
```

Your problem is that `CustomModel` is not a subclass of `ParentClass` and so its properties should not get filtered at all -- but they were, and were all filtered out, since they were not declared by `ParentClass`.

(I am not sure what you intended with `typeof(ParentClass).IsSubclassOf(member.DeclaringType)`.  The only base class of `ParentClass` is `object` which has no properties.)

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMs9Hb).

Comment: Bingo! This solved my problem. Thanks a lot.